# Dynamic Tabitem with Predefined Template

Tags: wpf, templates, dynamic, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a WPF app which creates tab dynamically,now I want the **every tab item must contain expander and Usercontrol** and also ill **set the datacontext for Expander and Usercontrol during run time**, so if i define the template for tabitem in Style,i feel it wuld be difficult for setting datacontext for expnder and usercontrol. In order for HeaderTemplate

XAML Code

```
<TabControl Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  FontWeight="Normal"    FontStretch="Expanded" >
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="150,0,0,0" Content="X" Foreground="WhiteSmoke"  FontSize="10" 
                               FontWeight="Bold"   Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" Height="15"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}"   >
                            <Button.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF9D4040" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB11212" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Button.Background>
                            <!--<Image Source="/delete.gif" Height="11" Width="11"></Image>-->
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem }, Path=Header}"  />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
```

**In codebehind ill add the content,**

```
     Private Function AddTabItem() As TabItem
        Dim count As Integer = _tabItems.Count

        Dim tab As New TabItem()

        tab.Header = String.Format("tab{0}", count)
        tab.Name = String.Format("tab{0}", count)
        tab.HeaderTemplate = TryCast(tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader"), DataTemplate)

        _tabItems.Insert(count - 1, tab)

          obj = New ThumbnailImages

        ' add controls to tab item, 
        If ImageCollection.Count > 0 Then
            obj.SetDataContext(ImageCollection)
            tab.Content = obj
        End If
        Return tab
    End Function
```

Now i need the **content to be templated with expander and Usercontrol**, how can i achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `ContentTemplate` to the `TabControl` (or `TabItem` if you prefer). I would do it all in XAML:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Expander>
        <my:UserControl />
      </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Because this is a template, the `DataContext` will be the `ThumbnailImages` object you're setting as the content to the `TabControl`.

Another thing I would mention is that you can set the `HeaderTemplate` property of the `TabControl` so you don't have to access it in code. And if you are dealing with multiple templates for the header and/or content, look into the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).

Comment: Thanx for ur reply, this s not wat i need.. I found solution ,i ahve added the Expander in my usercontrol, bcz expander has some complex logic and then i have added the usercontrol in tab item.